# How do I hide a specific volume from the desktop, but keep all others?

Tags: partitioning, icons, customization, gconf

I find the icons that show up when I plug a flash drive useful, as much as SD cards and devices. However, the icon to my Windows partition is useless. How can I hide it?

Comment: I like to add something. Is there any way, hide drive icon without unmounting that drive?

Answer (score 3):

To hide a partition, mount the partitions in your '/mnt' folder.  I use the fstab file to accomplish this automatically on boot up.

Answer (score 0):

Eject or unmount those which are not in use. This way, the icon will disappear from the desktop but will yet be listed in the file browser folder tree (in the sidebar) and in the devices listed. And will be available to gain access to the data contained in the device just with a clic.

This screenshot is having the SD memory connected and mounted, both the icon and the folder tree showing the device.

[image]

This screenshot is having the SD memory connected and NOT mounted, the device is shown in the folder tree but not in the desktop.

[image]