# How to only show certain partitions in external HDD?

Tags: 11.04, mount, home-directory, external-hdd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hide a specific volume from the desktop, but keep all others?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30830/how-do-i-hide-a-specific-volume-from-the-desktop-but-keep-all-others)

When I plug in my external hard drive with three partitions, it shows up as three drives. (I know it's supposed to be like that btw). Is there any way to hide certain partitions?

I have Ubuntu installed on my external hard drive, and I have three partitions on it: Home, "/", and swap. I use it to copy files directly to my external Home partition so that they will already be in my Home folder next time I boot from the drive. Is there a way to only show my Home partition when I plug it in? Obviously I still need to be able to access the "/" and "swap", but only when I am booted up into Ubuntu from the drive.