# Show USB drives in launcher, but not mounted internal partitions

Tags: unity, mount, usb-drive

Well the title pretty much says it all. I have partitions that appear in the launcher when the system mounts them, just like when a USB key is plugged in.

I do not want these mounted internal hard disc partitions to show as icons in the launcher, but I do want my external USB to show there when I plug it in.

I've tried MyUnity - it has only an option to not show/hide *all* mounted devices, which is not what I want.

Can this be done?

[image]

From `/proc/mounts` (in order seen in screenshot):

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/CEDD-DE31 vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/sda3 /media/A423-E0E8 vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/sda5 /media/586C25656C253EDE fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sda6 /home/greg/80gb ext4 rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
```

Other items from `/proc/mounts` not appearing in Unity launcher:

```
/dev/sda1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/sda9 /mnt/backup ext4 rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I'd forgotten about this question. I can add a screenshot and the output of that file if necessary, but I believe it's not possible to achieve what I want. Basically I'm after a Windows-like behavior where partitions will show *only* in the files explorer and plugged-in USB keys will be displayed as a new device each time. Please tell me if I'm not making myself clear.

Comment: Never mind, it can be done. Added the answer. Thanks @izx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here [How do I hide a specific volume from the desktop, but keep all others?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30830/how-do-i-hide-a-specific-volume-from-the-desktop-but-keep-all-others)

I had my partitions mounted in `/media/` at startup via the `/etc/fstab` file. This way the partitions would show up in the left-side launcher just as a plugged-in USB key would. After editing the `fstab` file and mounting those partitions into `/mnt/`, they now don't show in the launcher but a plugged-in USB key does.