# Normal RAM usage for Ubuntu 12.04 + Unity?

Tags: 12.04, unity, ram, memory-usage, ram-usage

My system is Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit + Unity and it uses ~480Mb with no other processes-apps open, just the core system. Is this the expected amount? It seems a bit steep to me but perhaps this is normal behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ~480 MB is normal for a stock 64-bit 12.04 with Unity (I get similar).

Don't forget that what you call the "core" system is actually running a 3D desktop environment as well as lots of background services. Windows 7 SP1 x64 with Aero is in the same region.

This shouldnt be a problem on a system with 2gb or more of RAM  If you want to lower RAM usage, consider switching to a lighter version such as Lubuntu.

Comment: Thank you! Just wanted some confirmation.
(PD: sorry for not responding your request for so long in my question http://askubuntu.com/questions/170035/only-show-external-usb-when-mounted-not-mounted-partitions; I'd forgotten about it)